# calculate network delay between client and server

Tags: php, javascript

check this link  http://tinyurl.com/l96z2m2

It retrieves client device time using javascript and Server time using php. and delay is the  network round trip time i.e., time between request sent and response received.

I want to compare both times at same point. have to ignore network delay.

It should be possible by calculating either time between 'request sent at client' and 'request received at server'  OR  time between 'request received at server' and 'response received at client'.

index.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
var b = new Date();
$.getJSON("http://localhost/json.php?callback=?", function(data){
var a = new Date();
document.write("|Client-"+a.getUTCHours()+":"+a.getUTCMinutes()+":"+a.getUTCSeconds()+":"+a.getUTCMilliseconds()+"|    Server-"+data.time);
  var c = a - b;
document.write("|delay-"+c);
});
</script>
```

json.php

```
<?php
$callback = $_GET["callback"];

function udate($format, $utimestamp = null) {
if (is_null($utimestamp))
$utimestamp = microtime(true);

$timestamp = floor($utimestamp);
$milliseconds = round(($utimestamp - $timestamp) * 1000000);

return date(preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', $milliseconds, $format), $timestamp);
}

 $t =  udate('H:i:s:u');

 echo $callback . "({
 \"time\":\"$t\"

 })";
 ?>
```

Comment: This site is not for "experts to find a solution for you". You're supposed to post what you've tried, and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Are you wanting to do calculations at the server or at the browser? And exactly what are you trying to do?? Your question is a bit vague to me.

Comment: @Barmar the link i posted is what i already tried.

Comment: I don't see any code at that link, just a line of output. If you want help with your code, you have to post it.

Comment: @RayPerea  calculations at server or client is not a problem. But what i am looking for is to calculate network delay between client and server.

Comment: @Barmar i posted it just now. please check it.

Comment: @Barmar I understood that you want to calculate network delay between the client and server... My question was... Where do you want to calculate the delay between client and server?? Namely what is going to be doing the calculations... Will the client be doing the calculations or will the server?

Comment: @Barmar  calculations at server.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are re-doing NTP in HTTP. You can look at how NTP protocol works http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol.

In short, you can easily measure the round trip time between server and client. And NTP made an assumption that the time between two trips (client -> server, and server -> client) is symmetric.

You may want run this clock skew calculation for 3+ times and minimum of them for a better measure.

Also note that your RTT includes time spent on OS/HTTP stack, so the final number may not be as accurate as the NTP protocol.

Comment: i want calculate server and client time difference accurately upto milli seconds. so  assuming two trips (client -> server, and server -> client) as symmetric wont help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize that it isn't as simple as take the server time and the client time and calculate the different to get network latency...

If you take the client UTC time and the server UTC time there is no guarantee that the network latency is the difference between the two, as the client can change their time and make it invalid.

But if you assume that that is the delay, you would do something like the following:

**JavaScript:**

```
var d = Date.UTC();
```

> Returns the number of milliseconds between a specified date and midnight January 1 1970

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    //Get miliseconds since 1970
    $time = time() * 1000;
    echo $time;
?>
```

> In PHP you can simply call time() to get the time passed since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT in seconds. If you want milliseconds just do (time()*1000).

With the above make a PHP RESTful service and then call the service using ajax in JavaScript or do the PHP part then compare the two in JavaScript, by doing something like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var serverTime = "<?php Print(time() * 1000); ?>";
    var clientTime = Date.UTC();
    var delay = clientTime - serverTime;
</script>
```

Comment: I want to know how much difference between server time and client devices time. so i want to eliminate network delay for accuracy upto milli seconds.

Comment: @VaibhavChiruguri according to PHP5 even microtime isn't accurate to the millisecond...So good luck i'll leave this answer for reference but will delete it when someone posts an acceptable answer.